# How can I create a table or data frame of members of a group (items by group, from long format data)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working with some cluster analysis results. I am trying to create tables of cluster members for each the cluster analyses I'm doing.

For example:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
        Cluster = sample(1:5,100,replace=T),
        Item = sample(LETTERS[1:20],5, replace=F))

head(test_data)
  Cluster Item
1       2    R
2       5    F
3       1    T
4       5    Q
5       3    B
6       3    J
```

I would like to produce something like this:

```
    Cluster_1   Cluster_2   Cluster_3   Cluster_4   Cluster_5
         T           R           C           P           L 
         K           O           J           M           Q
         I           H           B           N           F
         D                                   G           E
         S                                               A
```

I first tried `spread` , but didn't work with these data

```
spread(test_data, item,group)
```

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

```
spread(test_data, group,item)
```

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

Then I tried:

```
test_frame <- split.data.frame(test_data,test_data$group)
```

But that results in a list of data frames, with a data frame for each group. I haven't been able to successfully manipulate that into what I want.

I tried `unnest` and `unlist`, but because each group has a different number of member elements, those functions give errors.

Introducing NA's would be fine.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test_data <- data.frame(
       Cluster = sample(1:5,100,replace=T),
          Item = sample(LETTERS[1:20],5, replace=T),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

m <- with(test_data,tapply(Item,paste("Cluster",Cluster,sep="_"),I))
e <- data.frame(sapply(m,`length<-`,max(lengths(m))))
   print(e,na.print="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-worked my answer. All in base R. reasonably concise:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  Cluster = sample(1:5,100,replace=T),
  Item = sample(LETTERS[1:20],5, replace=T), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

clusters <- unique(test_data$Cluster)

test_data <- lapply(clusters, function(i) {
  test_data[test_data$Cluster == i,]$Item } ) 

n_max <- Reduce(f=max, x=lapply(test_data, FUN=length))

test_data <- lapply(test_data, function(i) {length(i) <- n_max; i})

test_data <- Reduce(x=test_data, f=cbind)

test_data <- as.data.frame(test_data)

names(test_data) <- paste0('Cluster_', clusters)

test_data
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I get an error with the above code:
'Error in Reduce(., cbind) : argument "init" is missing, with no default'

Comment: Now it's losing the data: 

`str(test_data3)
 Named int 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "Cluster_"`

Comment: The latest edit is close, but it coerces each element to integer. My data are actually strings (item names) so I need to keep those strings intact as characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `tidyverse`. `test_final` is the final output.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create example data frame
test_data <- data.frame(
  Cluster = sample(1:5,100,replace=T),
  Item = sample(LETTERS[1:20],5, replace=T))

# Split the data frame into a list of data frames
test_list <- test_data %>%
  mutate(Item = as.character(Item)) %>%
  arrange(Cluster) %>%
  split(f = .$Cluster)

# Find out the maximum row number of each data frame
max_row <- max(map_int(test_list, nrow))

# Design a function to process each data frame in test_list
process_fun <- function(dt, max_row){

  # Append NA to the Item column
  dt_vec <- dt$Item
  dt_vec2 <- c(dt_vec, rep(NA, max_row - nrow(dt)))
  # Get the cluster number
  clusterNum <- unique(dt$Cluster)
  # Create a new data frame
  dt2 <- data_frame(Item = dt_vec2)
  # Change column name
  colnames(dt2) <- paste("Cluster", clusterNum, sep = "_")
  return(dt2)
} 

# Process the data
test_final <- test_list %>% 
  map(process_fun, max_row = max_row) %>%
  bind_cols()
```